# Remove a string (filename) from a bigger string (the whole path)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say that I have this string `"D:\Users\Zache\Downloads\example.obj"` and I want to copy another file to the same directory as `example.obj`. How do I do this in a way that´s not hardcoded?

`"example"` can also be something else (user input). I'm using `filedialog2` to get the big string.

This is for an exporter with a basic GUI.

Comment: You should take a look at [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) gives you the directory portion of a given filename:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.dirname(r"D:\Users\Zache\Downloads\example.obj")
'D:\\Users\\Zache\\Downloads'
```

Comment: This is probably what I was looking for so I´l mark it as accepted. I do wonder why there is an 'r' before the string in the parameter of dirname.

Comment: @ZachariasHortén: I created a raw string to prevent ``\`` backslashes from being interpreted as part of escape sequences. I could have doubled them to ``\\`` as well, or used forward slashes, but I wanted to match your example more closely.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with str.split but this should be solved with os.path.split